# LIKE query with MySQL always return nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

First of all, I'm using rails 4.

What I'm trying to do is search some usernames in my MySQL database.

But whatever my query is, @search is nil, and the result is 404.

Here's my code.

I tried several changes with my params[:query] such as

"%#{params[:query]}%" or just params[:query] with out "%".

But it still didn't work

Any help will be appreciated.

```
def search_user
        @searh=User.where('username LIKE ?', "%"+params[:query]+"%").all
        if @search == nil 
            then
            head 404, content_type: "text/html"
            else
            render json: @search.to_json, status: 200
        end
    end
```

Comment: chek : def search_user
 query_search = "%#{params[:query]}%"
        @searh=User.where('username LIKE ?', query_search).all

Comment: Can you try `@search = User.where("username LIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%")`

Comment: make a string for the like parameter and thn pass it to query

Answer (score 2):

```
    def search_user
      @searh=User.where('username LIKE ?', "%#{params[:query]}%").all
        if @search == nil 
            then
            head 404, content_type: "text/html"
            else
            render json: @search.to_json, status: 200
        end
    end
```

i hope it's work in your code.

Comment: This works good, and I edited my database's character set to utf-8. I guess my search word was Korean, so there might be problem in encoding Korean in database. Anyway, this code is great.

Answer (score 0):

I always use it like:

```
@searh=User.where('username LIKE ?', "'%#{params[:query]}%'")
```

Notice that when the SQL query is generated, the pattern will be bounded by single quotes:

```
username LIKE '%whatever%'
```